# How convert Cats Effect 3 to Future

Tags: scala, playframework, cats-effect, tagless-final

I'm trying to combine Playframework with Cats Effect 3 Tagless Final style.

I'm stuck on the transformation to the Future. Play's Action requires either just value or Future, which I want to reach, for async processing.

```
def method = authed { _ => 
  val program: EitherT[IO, Throwable, Int] = ???
  program
}

def authed[F[_]: Async](fa: Request => F[Result]): Action = {
 ???
}
```

In cats effect 2 it was possible via `_.toIO.unsafeToFuture` but now it's changed.
According to the doc I must use [Dispatcher](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/std/dispatcher). Found the initial idea [on Github](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/issues/1048) but a new signature is `F[Future[A]]`

```
def beforeF[F[_]: Effect, A](fa: F[A]): Future[A] = fa.ioIO.unsafeToFuture()
// Note: Using a `Dispatcher` resource is cheap - don't worry about it
def preferredAfterF[F[_]: Async, A](fa: F[A]): F[Future[A]] = Dispatcher[F].use(_.unsafeToFuture(fa))
```

Does anyone have success?

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to create a `Dispatcher` for each request, which is wrong, you should create only one and pass it down to where you needed that way you will have just a `Future[A]`. Now, if you are able to use `IOApp` then you should be able to create the dispatcher there and combine it with all your other dependencies, if not then you would need to call `unsafeRunSync()` when you create the dispatcher.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez form my curiosity, may be I am a foolish, I have a question, is not it a redundancy using cats effects with playframwork ?

Comment: @John it depends, in theory, no since **cats-effect** is mostly about how you build programs and **Play** is more about the HTTP framework. However, it is true that the way **Play** works make interoperating with `IO` kind of difficult. - So, in general, I don't think **Play** + **cats-effect** is a good design to start a new project _(although that is also in part because I don't think that using **Play** at all to be a good idea)_, but is combination is a common step in the process of migrating from one ecosystem to another; also, the mix is NOT great to learn **cats-effect**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez can you kindly clear this part ' I don't think that using Play at all to be a good idea' ?

Comment: @John is mostly a personal opinion, I really don't like the architectural decisions made by **Play**, like having the front-end and back-end integrated into the same service, dependency injection, the way it manages SQL queries, the way it manages the build; etc.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez now I understand

Answer (score 1):

Contruct your routes so that they have access to a `Disptacher` object as a dependency, then the lifecycle will be appropriate

```scala
class MyRoute[F[_]: MonadThrow](disp: Dispatcher[F]) {
  def method = authed { _ => 
    val program: EitherT[IO, Throwable, Int] = ???
    disp.unsafeToFuture(program.value)
  }
}
```

(this might require some fiddling using `allocated` and the `IORuntime`'s unsafeRunSync on a `Dispatcher[IO]` resource, depending on how your application is wired)